# Windows XP won't load after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-xp

I am a newbie and just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Instead of using the automatic dual boot option, I installed it manually on the partition made for it, but now only Ubuntu loads up with no option to boot Windows XP. Pressing **F8** doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

You had to use Ubuntu install procedure to install Ubuntu alongside the windows. Now, most probably your Ubuntu overwrited the boot and your Winodws are out of booting procedure. I would recommend you to fix the boot record from the Windows CD and install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

There are ways how to edit grub settings (do you have grub?/dualboot?), but if you are 
a newbie, could be a hard job for you.

...And you can try this: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

for first you forget microsoft os but if you need to install it you install virtual box into your computer on ubuntu os and after that